# Can i replace util.inherits with es6's extend keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to transform some es5 code to es6 and I stumbled upon the following code and I am wondering if I could replace the `util.inherits` with the `extends` keyword for classes. I am a bit confused if they do the same thing.

### ES5

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

function TheEmitter() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(TheEmitter, EventEmitter);
```

### ES6

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class TheEmitter extends EventEmitter {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `class` and `extends` keywords are only syntactic sugar on top of prototypal inheritance, the answer simply is: Yes, you can replace `util.inherits` by `extends` and keep the same behavior.

Of course, there are minor things to watch out for, e.g. you need to make sure to call the `super` constructor in your derived class's constructor, whereas with `util.inherits` you had to call the constructor function and `apply` it to `this`. But effectively, these things are only other syntactic constructs, semantically, they are equivalent.

Then, of course, there are some practical issues, where both options differ from each other. E.g., when defining `Foo` using the `class` keyword, you can not call `Foo` without using the `new` keyword. Without the `class` keyword, this is perfectly possible (although not meaningful, so you shouldn't have done this anyway).

So, to cut a long story short: Apart from some strange effects that only happen if you used rare and strange constructs (like calling a constructor function without `new`), the transition should be seamless.